# TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I recently created a little ASP.NET Core MVC project for CRUD-related actions to work on my skills. I did some research and put up my project up through Heroku, so it can also be accessed publicly by friends/family.

The login/register pages are accessible, but when I try to login (already had 2 users before putting it up!) it goes to my Errors endpoint and says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

My connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=*mydatabaseherenamehere*;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
```

I tried for hours and did things like allowing remote connections to the SQL server. I have an SQLEXPRESS instance in my case, so I setup TCP/IP to enabled, in IPAll I changed dynamic ports to blank, TCP Port to 1433.

In my firewall, I set up rules for TCP on port 1433, even UDP on port 1434. Even a custom rule for SQLEXPRESS service.

I restarted my SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) many times.

I actually changed the dot in the beginning of the connection string to the actual server name. I tried it with the my IP address, as well. Also, inserting the port 1433 in the connection string.

May I get some assistance as I've never had to deal with this before, but I'd like to learn :)

Thank you!

Comment: If your instance is listening on port 1433, you can omit the instance name. Try `Server=.` or `Server=YourMachine`. Note the "Allow remote connections to this server" option in SSMS does not allow/disallow remote client connections; use SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: First, are you able to connect to it via some tool like Azure Data Studio/SSMS/DataGrip/dbForge for SQL Server/etc? Do you get any errors in these environments when connecting? The thing that I’m worried about is that you have your SQL Server in your in-home network on one of your computers or something that the deployed version on Heroku cannot access. If so, this becomes a networking question and you’ll need to learn about dynamic IPs and port forwarding.

Comment: There's a multitude of reasons this may happen: SQL Server is not installed on the local machine (which is what `.` refers to). Maybe you installed it on a different server? SQL Server is installed as a different instance name. SQL Server is installed but not started. SQL Browser service is not started (you are using an instance name so needs the Browser). On a local machine you should be using Shared Memory not TCP, so that needs to be enabled.